# python Search value in list

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have a list like: `"level_one_links"`:

```
mylinks = [ 
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-1",
        "link" : "/login"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-2",
        "link" : "/author/Albert-Einstein"
    },......................
]
```

Now I want to search for a link, for example /author/Albert-Einstein. If the link does not exist, I want to append it to the list, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: It's better to create your data as a dict keyed on `link`, although I suspect that this dict will fail to be useful for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert to a list that contains all the "link" fields and then use `in`, example:

```
mylinks = [
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-1",
        "link" : "/login"
    },
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-2",
        "link" : "/author/Albert-Einstein"
    }]

if "/author/Albert-Einstein" in [ x["link"] for x in mylinks ]:
    print("Found it!")
else:
    print("Not there...")
    # Append your new object
    mylinks.append({...})
```

Comment: Great @urban, I was searching for something faster like this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylinks = [
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-1",
        "link" : "/login"
    },
    {
        "type" : "np",
        "link_id" : "quotes-first-2",
        "link" : "/author/Albert-Einstein"
    }]

for element in mylinks:
    if element['link'] == "/author/Albert-Einstein":
        print(element)
        # do whatever with element or element's attr e.g element['type']...
```

Comment: Thanks @shahaf, but it will consume more time because I have huge data.

Comment: @bhattraideb if the list isn't sorted, or hashed you don't have any other choice of  iterate over the whole list, and all other version of this code as above will not gain much performance and are basically the same

Comment: In my case, list is stored on mongoDB and have to add link if it is not stored previously. Thanks.

Comment: @bhattraideb suggest you change it to a mongodb question.. cause you can query it on the db itself, much much faster than getting all results and iterate over them...

Comment: I don't see how the other answer is faster than this one. They both iterate the whole list. The other one just puts it in a list comp. It then has to iterate it again for the `in`.